# UDF Function to search files in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Here is my case, I have a `PRODUCTS` table

```
create table PRODUCTS 
(
  ID_PRODUCTS           CHAR(10) primary key not null,
  NAME                  CHAR(30),
  PRICE                 INTEGER
)
```

Then I fill it with some data,...

```
insert into PRODUCTS values('B1','Samsung Galaxy Ace 2',250)
insert into PRODUCTS values('B2','Samsung Galaxy Tab 3',375)
insert into PRODUCTS values('B3','Samsung Galaxy Note 2',700)
insert into PRODUCTS values('B4','Apple iPod Touch',200)
insert into PRODUCTS values('B5','Apple Macbook Pro',1250)
```

Then I want to create a stored function to search for data based a keyword on `NAME` column in `PRODUCTS` table. For example, when I execute that function with a `Samsung` keyword, it should be showing a list which contains word `Samsung` in the name. I hope the list will be like this the appearance

```
ID_PRODUCTS | NAME | PRICE
========================================
B1 | Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 | 250
B2 | Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 | 375
B3 | Samsung Galaxy Note 2 | 700
```

Here is the code, but it show nothing when execute it (`select * from dbo.products_fun`)

```
create function product_fun
(
   @name char(30)
)
returns TABLE
as
   return 
   (select * from products where name like '%@name%')
```

I think it show nothing because the query

```
select * from products where name like '%@name%'
```

It is not a search for keywords inside the variable @name, .. but the search for the keyword "@name",... that's why it show nothing when execute it. Anyone wanna help ???

Comment: I recommend you should use **`varchar(30)`** rather than `char(30)` which will be padded to its defined length of 30 characters with spaces...

Comment: okay, i'll do it,.... but how about the problem syntax my query select * from products where name like '%@name%',.... ???? Do you know where is my mistake ???

Comment: Try: `LIKE @Name + '%'`

Comment: it shows same thing,.... nothing appears just column no rows file selected

Comment: Weeww,.... it works pretty well so far, thanks for youe help, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said - for something like a product name, I would **never** use a `char(x)` value. `char(x)` should only be used for fixed-length strings of 3-5 characters in length, like e.g. ISO country codes, or currency symbols etc. Anything else should be `varchar(x)`.

This code works just fine:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS1
(ProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 ProductName VARCHAR(30),
 ProductPrice DECIMAL(16,2)
)

insert into PRODUCTS1(ProductName, ProductPrice) values('Samsung Galaxy Ace 2',250.0)
insert into PRODUCTS1(ProductName, ProductPrice) values('Samsung Galaxy Tab 3',375.0)
insert into PRODUCTS1(ProductName, ProductPrice) values('Samsung Galaxy Note 2',700.0)
insert into PRODUCTS1(ProductName, ProductPrice) values('Apple iPod Touch',200.0)
insert into PRODUCTS1(ProductName, ProductPrice) values('Apple Macbook Pro',1250.0)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION FindProducts (@name varchar(30))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Products1 WHERE Productname LIKE @name + '%' )
```

Now calling this function:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.FindProducts('Samsu')
```

returns this result set:

```
ProductID   ProductName             ProductPrice
   1        Samsung Galaxy Ace 2       250.00
   2        Samsung Galaxy Tab 3       375.00
   3        Samsung Galaxy Note 2      700.00
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,.... i'm very appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
create function product_fun
(
    @name varchar(30)
)
returns TABLE
as
return 
(
    select * from products 
    where name like '%' + @name + '%'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still shows nothing when i execute it 
select*from dbo.products_fun('Samsung')

Comment: The `char(30)` datatype of the parameter means whatever you pass to it will be padded out with trailing spaces.

Comment: updated: answered and didn't come back until 12 hours later! Sorry.